# How to maintain proper typescript type on Vue component data?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

I'm working on a Vue project that I'm updating to Vue 3 with typescript. I've found a strange behavior with the typescript parser/compiler.  I have the following component:

```
    export default defineComponent({
        name: 'Test',

        data() {
            return {
                test: new Child(),
            };
        },
        
        methods: {
            testMethod: function () {
                this.test = new Child(); 
                let test2 = new Child();
            }
        },
    });


    class Child {
        b = 0;
    }
```

In the method, the parser thinks that `test2` is of type `Child`.  But it thinks that `this.test` is of type `{b: number}` (i.e. it has lost the connection to `Child`.  Hovering over the data structure (vscode) shows that when it is created there it thinks the type is `Child`.

In this example, it's not really an issue because it can easily cast it. But if `Child` is instead defined as:

```
  class Parent {
     private a = 1;
  }
  class Child extends Parent {
     b = 0;
  }
```

then `this.test` still has the same type `{b:number}` (it loses the private member) and can no longer be cast to Parent.  This causes endless typecasting to `any` to work around.  Another symptom it isn't picking up the right type is that something like `this.test.a = 3` generates *property does not exist (ts2339)* while `test2.a = 3;` generates *property is private and only accessible with parent (ts2341)* (which is the correct error).

I've tried manually specifying the return type of data(), as well, with the same result.

Am I doing something wrong? Is this just how the Vue plugin works with Typescript?

Comment: Why isn't `b` declared with visibility and a type?

Comment: Simplicity in posting here. It doesn't change the behavior (and they're both inferred regardless)

Comment: Sadly I haven't done enough work with Vue 3 to answer your question, one thing I did notice though is that the problem is not related to the assignment to `this.test`. If you omit that line and instead do `let foo = this.test`, the types are wrong as well.

Comment: It might be worth adding a link to a [Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgEwKYDNgDtUGELgQ5bwC+c6UBcA5AG4CuqNAUCwMYA2AhgM69xcAC2CdkiFnClwARnAC8cAAwBuFqTUtUAD0iwUGbg07w0mHPkLEYACgSTpWbiFQAuWgBVUvGDQA0bNIo3DDcNgCUEkFBUKgwDFBYUdEpMN4w7jgA7oIiYhEBKVIaDsWF0qVwLjBCEMi87vZFcGk+ALJxtcju6AxY7DDARHARyc1SAPQTcB4AnmCocBDocAAGYFQynKggq3C8tcbiMourwqLIq36yDPDAAqtIMpkMICdQcKR72D6o3MiVZrbeAbCBbHYKFoiXgAOlaMDU42kNXucPSkOyuQuERUcEBRWBLXSACYMagcud8uFEUVSJVSAFSNSWEA) to the question.

Comment: That's right - the assignment was just to have some valid code to illustrate the issue.  The parser doesn't properly understand the type of `this.test`.  Thanks for the suggestion and the playground.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As outlined [here](https://github.com/vuejs/core/issues/5840), the issue is that the `data` items are reactive, and in the wrapping/unwrapping, the class is lost.

The solution there indicates that using a shallowRef() is indicated (because keeping the instance raw for something so complex is preferred generally):

```
export default defineComponent({
        name: 'Test',

        setup() {
            return {
                test: shallowRef(new Child()),
            };
        },

      ...
        
    });
```

If you don't mind (or prefer) the wrapper, simply changing `data` to `setup` will fix the typing issue:

```
export default defineComponent({
        name: 'Test',

        setup() {
            return {
                test: new Child(),
            };
        },
        
        ...
    });
```